# How to Link ORACLE Data with MS Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have 3 modules in Oracle and there are some query which I run on daily basis to extract the required data.

I am not sure if I can do it hrough VBA. Is it Possible? I have tried to build up a macro which will combine the data but it was not working.

Please help.

Best Regards!!

Comment: It is doable. Would it be possible to see what you've tried in the past (anonymising passwords and the like along the way)? The question as it stands is pretty open and shows minimal research on the topic - liekly why you've been downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using `Data, Get External Data, From Other Sources, ODBC`.
Try it out first, then use the recorder if required. But I'd think that once it is set-up, you only need to refresh the data.
Alternatively, you could also try `Insert, Pivot Table, Use an external data source`

*The best macro is no macro (from an MS book on macros back in the 90's)

So many people start writing Excel vba because they just don't know that what they want is already available in Excel!*

Answer (score 0):

I use DAO to connect between Excel (2007) and my databases (typically MS Access).

To do this, you need to:

Add Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library to your VBAProject References (i.e. Tools ─► References).

code would look something like this:

```
Sub MySub() 
  Set Db = OpenDatabase("C:\MyDB.mdb") 
  Set rst = Db.OpenRecordset(" SELECT * FROM MyTable") 
  ' output (BULK DUMP) 
  Sheets.Add 
  With ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 1) 
     rec_QTY = .CopyFromRecordset(rst) 
  End With 
  rst.Close 
  Db.Close 
End Sub
```

Or if you want to execute a specific command:

```
Sub MySub_single_command()
  Set Db = OpenDatabase("C:\MyDB.mdb")
  Db.Execute (" DELETE * FROM MyTable;")
  Db.Close
End Sub
```

There are other methods in DAO for manipulating / dumping specific data from a data set.

cheers, Mike